# Arduino not receiving serial port write command

Tags: java, vb.net, arduino

Currently, I am trying to migrate my vb code to java code. Now, my arduino is running in vb code but its not running in my java code. I have tried to change the written values but its seems the same.

This is my working vb code:

```
 Dim data1 As String = "1"
 ComArduino.Write(data1)
```

This is my arduino code:

```
if (Serial.available()>0){
delay(100);
num1 = digitalRead(ir_in1);
num2 = digitalRead(ir_Two);
val=Serial.read();
Serial.println(val);
switch (val) {
case '1':  
  num2 = digitalRead(ir_Two);
```

This is my current java code which is not working:

```
 String number = "1";

 byte num[] = number.getBytes();
 for(int i =0; i<num.length;i++){
    outputStream.write(num[i]);

 }
 outputStream.flush();
```

The main objective of this program to send the string value "1" to the arduino and rest the arduino will do. Can any Arduino and java expert help me with this pls. Thank you.

Comment: can you post the declaration code of `outputStream`, its settings and all that

Comment: OutputStream outputStream; this is the declaration code

Comment: If I try the same code for different com port it's working

Comment: see... thats what i need... everyone knows `outputstream` is of type `OutputStream`... post the code in your question with the settings and all that of `outputStream`.The code you gave is correct so its evident that the problem lies somewhere else